# Refresh Bound Datagridview after TableAdapter Update without Fill

Tags: c#, .net, data-binding, datagridview, tableadapter

I've been searching here and on google this for the last 2 hours and I haven't been able to find a solution to this!

The only way I can get a `DataGridView` to reflect the changes made by `TableAdapter.Update` is to use `TableAdapter.Fill` but the problem with that is that the `DataGridView` scrolls back to the top.

How can I 'refresh' the DGV without losing it's state? I know I can get and set the state after fill but surely there is a better way to do it!!

Here is my very simple test app...

```
    private Random Rand = new Random();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MyTableAdapter.Fill(this.MyDataSet.MyTable);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string _rand = Convert.ToString(Rand.Next(1000, 5000));
        this.MyTableAdapter.UpdateStatus(_rand, "111.222.333.444");
        label1.Text = _rand;
    }
```

Where `MyTableAdapter.UpdateStatus` SQL = `UPDATE MyTable SET status=@p1 WHERE (ip=@p2)`

It works as it should except the DGV does not update without `Fill`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the TableAdapter's `ClearBeforeFill` property to `False` will stop this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

if you set ClearBeforeFill property to False it will add the same data over and over, every .Fill